# PowerShell: How to group by multiple attributes from an XML document?

Tags: powershell

I'm brand new to XML so I have a question about how to manipulate XML data.  My current data has an EmployeeID in 2 different segments (not sure of terminology here, maybe attribute).  I want to combine the segments per EmployeeID and TimeOfDay and ensure all data for an EmployeeID is in one segment.

I thought about trying this in another language, but I'd like to see how it's done in PowerShell.  How could I do this?

It needs to be grouped by EmployeeID and TimeOfDay.

The current code doesn't return any results.

```
$xmlPath = 'XMLFilePath' 
$xdoc = new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$xdoc.Load($xmlPath)
$xdoc.SelectNodes('//Employees/EmployeeID') | Group-Object { $_.ParentNode.key },{ $_.Dimension.value.Substring(0,7) } -NoElement
```

**Current Data:**

```
<Employees>
  <Employee>
    <EmployeeID>9999999999</EmployeeID>
    <DaysOfWeekShort></DaysOfWeekShort>
    <TimeOfDay>AM</TimeOfDay>
    <BusNumber>7777</BusNumber>
    <TimeOfDay>AM</TimeOfDay>
    <BusNumber>9999</BusNumber>
  </Employee>
  <Employee>
    <EmployeeID>9999999999</EmployeeID>
    <DaysOfWeekShort></DaysOfWeekShort>
    <TimeOfDay>PM</TimeOfDay>
    <BusNumber>8888</BusNumber>
  </Employee>
</Employees>
```

**Desired Result:**

```
<Employees>
  <Employee>
    <EmployeeID>9999999999</EmployeeID>
    <DaysOfWeekShort></DaysOfWeekShort>
    <TimeOfDay>AM</TimeOfDay>
    <BusNumber>7777</BusNumber>
    <BusNumber>9999</BusNumber>
    <TimeOfDay>PM</TimeOfDay>
    <BusNumber>8888</BusNumber>
  </Employee>
</Employees>
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited the desired output and current data.  The Current Data has the same employee twice.  Also, the Bus Numbers are not grouped in AM / PM, respectively.

Comment: Ehh... I think you'll want to group the `Employee` nodes by `EmployeeID` (_not_ `TimeOfDay`, values are different), eg. `$groupedEmployees = $xdoc.SelectNodes('//Employees/Employee[EmployeeID]') | Group-Object EmployeeID`